# Jersey ClassNotFoundException when contextInitialized

Tags: java, maven, servlets, jersey, tomcat8

When I connect to the selected servlet, it throw me a ClassNotFoundException. I am using eclipse neon with Tomcat8 and jersey RESTful framework. Its possible that I have the servlet conf in wrong in the web.xml?

**Error showed:**

```
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet jersey
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:518)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:499)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:828)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**My web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>org.CTAG.DATEX2REST</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <display-name>CTAG DATEX2</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.CTAG.DATEX2REST</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            com.CTAG.application.Init
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

**The POM.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.CTAG.DATEX2REST</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.CTAG.DATEX2REST</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>org.CTAG.DATEX2REST Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>org.CTAG.DATEX2REST</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Please let me know if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your `web.xml` content is incorrect, it matches with `Jersey 2.x` while you obviously use `Jersey 1.x`, indeed the package names start with `com.sun.jersey` in `Jersey 1.x` while in `Jersey 2.x` they start with `org.glassfish.jersey`.

Check [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/jax-rs.html#d4e223) what should be the content of your `web.xml` in case of `Jersey 1.x.`.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>org.CTAG.DATEX2REST</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Or switch to `Jersey 2.x`.

Answer (score 1):

### Fixing the dependencies

You are mixing Jersey 1.x (`com.sun.jersey`) and Jersey 2.x (`org.glassfish.jersey`).

I understand you wan't to use Jersey 2.x, so remove:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

And then add to your `pom.xml`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <!-- if your container implements Servlet API older 
         than 3.0, use "jersey-container-servlet-core"  -->
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.2</version>
</dependency>
```

### Deploying in a Servlet 2.x container (like Tomcat 6)

Jersey integrates with any Servlet containers supporting at least Servlet 2.5 specification. For these environments, you have to explicitly declare the Jersey container servlet in your web application's `web.xml` deployment descriptor file:

```xml
<web-app>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            ...
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

The content of the `<init-param>` element will vary depending on the way you decide to configure Jersey resources.

### Deploying in a Servlet 3.x container (like Tomcat 7 and above)

In a Servlet 3.0 container, you just need to implement a custom [`Application`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) / [`ResourceConfig`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html) subclass. For simple deployments, no `web.xml` is necessary at all. Instead, an [`@ApplicationPath`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23/jersey/javax/ws/rs/ApplicationPath.html) annotation can be used to annotate the custom [`Application`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) / [`ResourceConfig`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html) subclass and define the base application URI for all JAX-RS resources configured in the application:

```java
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyApplication() {
        packages("org.foo.rest;org.bar.rest");
    }
}
```

---

For other deployment options, have a look at the [documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html).

Comment: Cassio, sorry for my late feedback, I am full focused learning jersey and I didn´t realize write to you. Indeed your answer solve my question, but now, I deal with the fact that is like jersey in geral are not running due to the fact that the URL throw always 404.

Comment: Thank you Cassio, I have solved my problem changing ResourceConfig.packages() by ResorceConfig.register()

Comment: but I am not able to understand why

Comment: @datex2 I'm not sure. I think it depends on what you are trying to register :) I'm happy to know you've sorted it.